# angularjs object changes affects other object

Tags: angularjs

I have AngularJS application. From server I am getting a JSON. I am assigning to two objects. One I am using in my form page to edit. When the user press submit, I want to check whether the new value and old are same. But whenever I update the value in form and checks, the other object value also gets updated., resulting both object becomes same always.

[Here is the JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fc0jo1so/). Whenever I am trying to change the value, the other value also gets updated.

What is the solution to prevent the other object to not change?

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Form</h2>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="myForm" ng-submit="saveForm()">
      <input type="text" ng-model="obj.name">
          <input type="text" ng-model="obj.value">
      <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" ng-disabled="myForm.$pristine">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.obj={
        name:"N1",
        value:"val"};

    var oldObj = $scope.obj;

    $scope.saveForm=function() {
        alert(JSON.stringify($scope.obj));
        alert(JSON.stringify(oldObj));
        if($scope.obj===oldObj){
            alert("same");
         } else {
            alert("not same");
         }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just change this line

var oldObj = angular.copy($scope.obj);

Try it will work. & give alert not same

Comment: I prefer this one. Simple

Comment: So you got the solution, but you didn't understand the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you just store an **reference** to `oldObj`. 
So `oldObj` and the `$scope.obj` is always the same.

You need to copy it.

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fc0jo1so/1/

I did it with fromJson, toJson

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery to make a deep copy

```
var oldObj = jQuery.extend(true, {}, $scope.obj);
```